# Moving UITableViewCell rows between sections crashes my application

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Before I get any infractions from duplicating questions, I just wanted to say that I apologize and I've been searching for some way to solve this problem for a day now and I haven't gotten anywhere close to where I want to be.

So, I want to move one of my UITableView rows from one section to another. So, for example, I have a recipe that is in the "Snacks" section and I want to move that to the "Breakfast" section. I was able to move it once, but when I move it another time, I get the Array Index Out Of Bounds error.

I was able to move the rows within their each section without crashing, but moving between sections is where I'm stuck at.

**Edit**: The error message is: **fatal error: Index out of range** and it's crashing at "let recipeNameToMove = recipesToBeMoved[rowNumberFrom]"

Also, to make this a little bit more clear, I have 4 sections: "Breakfast", "Dinner", "Lunch", "Snacks" -> These are keys from the savedRecipes plist (where I store all the recipe information from the Yummly API).

So far, this is what my recipesArray looks like with one entry:

```
[["Strawberry Jalapeno Pico De Gallo","4","https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/2yZhMGgfnREb2OPcEpzKjHogS2hTClhcRr3OVfp6batG_m4iRWI1cKBKixfv089_yrgblDTKZlq3PFtbPvSWeQ=s90-c", "0g", "0g", "0g", "0g", "No Data", "0mg", "0mg", "26g", "7g", "11g", "3g", "8%", "216%", "9%", "0%", "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/naElDNklXjL9lxhL2C198_IUshv9aA82LEL_2ZFl3ATAL3m4dRDDTo9DpqeCxBCdR_R6061olbZ2B4LYqh6jRQ=s360", "124", "10 min", "1", "http://www.rhubarbarians.com/strawberry-jalapeno-pico-de-gallo/"]]
```

And this is what the recipeNameToMove looks like:

```
["Strawberry Jalapeno Pico De Gallo", "4", "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/2yZhMGgfnREb2OPcEpzKjHogS2hTClhcRr3OVfp6batG_m4iRWI1cKBKixfv089_yrgblDTKZlq3PFtbPvSWeQ=s90-c", "0g", "0g", "0g", "0g", "No Data", "0mg", "0mg", "26g", "7g", "11g", "3g", "8%", "216%", "9%", "0%", "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/naElDNklXjL9lxhL2C198_IUshv9aA82LEL_2ZFl3ATAL3m4dRDDTo9DpqeCxBCdR_R6061olbZ2B4LYqh6jRQ=s360", "124", "10 min", "1", "http://www.rhubarbarians.com/strawberry-jalapeno-pico-de-gallo/"]
```

Here is my code for my moveRowAtIndexPath method:

```
//---------------------------
// Movement of Row Attempted
//---------------------------

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    // Obtain the section of the recipe to be deleted

    let sectionOfRecipe = sectionTypeArray[fromIndexPath.section]

    // Obtain the list of recipes from each section
    let recipes: AnyObject? = applicationDelegate.savedRecipesDict[sectionOfRecipe]

    // Typecast the anyobject to a swift array
    var recipesArray = recipes as! [[String]]

    // Row number to move FROM
    let rowNumberFrom = fromIndexPath.row

    // Row number to move TO
    let rowNumberTo = toIndexPath.row

    // Section number to move FROM
    let sectionNumberFrom = fromIndexPath.section

    // Section number to move TO
    let sectionNumberTo = toIndexPath.section

    // If the recipe cells are moving outside of their sections
    if sectionNumberFrom != sectionNumberTo
    {
        // Where the application crashes on the second move
        let recipeNameToMove = recipesArray[rowNumberFrom]

        // If movement is from lower part of the list to upper part
        if sectionNumberFrom > sectionNumberTo
        {
            recipesToBeMoved.insert(recipeNameToMove, atIndex: rowNumberTo)
            recipesToBeMoved.removeAtIndex(rowNumberFrom + 1)
        }
        else
        {
            // Movement is from upper part to lower part
            recipesToBeMoved.insert(recipeNameToMove, atIndex: rowNumberTo + 1)
            recipesToBeMoved.removeAtIndex(rowNumberFrom)
        }

        print("Moving out of sections")
        print(rowNumberFrom)

        applicationDelegate.savedRecipesDict.setValue(recipesToBeMoved, forKey: sectionOfRecipe)


    }


}
```

This is how I get an array of my section (i.e. Breakfast, Lunch, etc.)

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Adding in rounded corners to the buttons
    logCaloriesButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    recommendFoodButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8;

    sectionTypeArray = applicationDelegate.savedRecipesDict.allKeys as! [String]

    // Sort the selection names within itself in alphabetical order
    sectionTypeArray.sortInPlace { $0 < $1 }

}
```

Thank you so much for your time! :)

Comment: You need to update your question with more specific details. What is the complete error message? Which line exactly causes the error?

Comment: Just edited! Thanks! :)

Comment: I think you need to work on your data structure.  How do you define each section?  Typically you would have one array for each section and it looks like you are storing these in a dictionary, but I can't see where you access the destination array from the dictionary.  Also I think you will find your code much cleaner if you create a class to represent each recipe and put instances of that class in the array rather than an array of strings

Comment: @Paul11, I've updated my answer. Yes, I am storing these arrays in the plist. Each section is a String array along with the array of strings (recipes). The plist is a dictionary that is comprise of an array for the section headers, and another array to hold the recipe information. So thus, it is an array within an array within a dictionary. Also, I see what you mean and I'll try it out that way after I have gotten somewhere on this problem. Thanks! :)